# How to get all object children in one query?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.11

I have a person model. Each person has it's children. Children may have children as well. I want to get all children (recursively) in one query. How can I do that?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def add_person(request):
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        name = request.POST['name']
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        person = Person(name=name, parent_id=parent_id)
        person.save()

        return redirect('/persons')
    else:
        return render(request, 'add_person.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
Person.objects.all().prefetch_related('children')
```

What does it do? As state in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), it will:

> automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

It fetches the date you want and also will save some database i/o.

To filter by a name:

```
Person.objects.filter(name='Vladislav').prefetch_related('children')
```